# Replace element tag to empty tag

Tags: java, xml, xslt, encoding, utf-8

My requirements is to generate an empty element with the given scenario. I have the same in this [Replacing the element tag with value to end tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266870/replacing-the-element-tag-with-value-to-end-tag). However, the output generated is not what I am expecting.

**CONDITION:** 
Map according to priority:
1. **If** Test1 is equal to Payment1, generate this empty element `<st:Test1/>` 2. **else if** Test2 is equal to Payment2, generate this empty element `<st:Test2/>` 3. **else if** Test3 is equal to Payment3, generate this empty element `<st:Test3/>`.

**MY XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:st="http://www.ebinterface.at/schema/4p1/" xmlns:po="http://schema.ebinterface.at/schema/4p1/" exclude-result-prefixes="po">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="st:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="po:DEFG" priority="1">
        <st:DEFG>
            <!--handle any existing child content-->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(po:Test1)">
                <xsl:call-template name="Test1"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="not(po:Test2)">
                <xsl:call-template name="Test2"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="not(po:Test3)">
                <xsl:call-template name="Test3"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </st:DEFG>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="po:Test1[.='Payment1']" name="Test1" priority="1">
        <st:Test1/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="po:Test2[.='Payment2']" name="Test2" priority="1">
        <st:Test2/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="po:Test3[.='Payment3']" name="Test3" priority="1">
        <st:Test3/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='http://www.ebinterface.at/schema/4p1/']">
        <xsl:element name="po:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='http://www.ebinterface.at/schema/4p1/']/@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="po:{local-name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**INPUT FILE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Statistics xmlns="http://schema.ebinterface.at/schema/4p1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ebinterface.at/schema/4p1/" Type="abc" Title="Statistics">
     <ABC dsig="fh">Sample ABC</ABC>
     <DEFG>
        <Note>Wir ersuchen um termingerechte Bezahlung.</Note>
        <Amount currencyCode="EUR">12.36</Amount>
        <Test1>Payment1</Test1>
     </DEFG>
</Statistics>
```

**GENERATED OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<st:Statistics xmlns:st="http://www.ebinterface.at/schema/4p1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ebinterface.at/schema/4p1/" Type="abc" Title="Statistics">
    <st:ABC dsig="fh">Sample ABC</st:ABC>
    <st:DEFG>
        <st:Note>Wir ersuchen um termingerechte Bezahlung.</st:Note>
        <st:Amount currencyCode="EUR">12.36</st:Amount>
        <st:Test1/>
        <st:Test2/> **This empty element should not appear since there's no Test2=Payment2**
        <st:Test3/> **This empty element should not appear since there's no Test3=Payment3**
    </st:DEFG>
</st:Statistics>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<st:Statistics xmlns="http://schema.ebinterface.at/schema/4p1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ebinterface.at/schema/4p1/" st:Type="abc" st:Title="Statistics">
    <st:ABC st:dsig="fh">Sample ABC</st:ABC>
    <st:DEFG>
        <st:Note>Wir ersuchen um termingerechte Bezahlung.</st:Note>
        <st:Amount st:currencyCode="EUR">12.36</st:Amount>
        <st:Test1/>
    </st:DEFG>
</stStatistics>
```

Thank you in advance.

Your response is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a template by name, that template will be executed regardless of whether it matches anything or not.

Not directly related to your question, you also have a template conflict between `<xsl:template match="@* | node()">` and `<xsl:template match="*">`. Overall, you have way too much code; I believe you could do with just:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:po="http://schema.ebinterface.at/schema/4p1/"
xmlns:st="http://www.ebinterface.at/schema/4p1/"
exclude-result-prefixes="po">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- move elements to new namespace -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="st:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- move attributes to new namespace -->
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="st:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<!-- except attributes that are NOT in the default namespace -->
<xsl:template match="@*[namespace-uri()]">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="po:Test1[.='Payment1']">
    <st:Test1/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="po:Test2[.='Payment2']">
    <st:Test2/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="po:Test3[.='Payment3']">
    <st:Test3/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<st:Statistics xmlns:st="http://www.ebinterface.at/schema/4p1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ebinterface.at/schema/4p1/" st:Type="abc" st:Title="Statistics">
   <st:ABC st:dsig="fh">Sample ABC</st:ABC>
   <st:DEFG>
      <st:Note>Wir ersuchen um termingerechte Bezahlung.</st:Note>
      <st:Amount st:currencyCode="EUR">12.36</st:Amount>
      <st:Test1/>
   </st:DEFG>
</st:Statistics>
```

**Note**:

1. The three choices are not mutually exclusive as your question would suggest.
2. Your expected output is not well-formed XML: you cannot have a prefix without binding it to a namespace.